# Waiting for AJAX request response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following function that stores some data in `ABC.PrintReport.reportData`.
I grab the data with AJAX requests. I then want to print the data in the new window that I open at the end of the `getKeyData` function.

However, by the time the window opens, the AJAX requests have not returned the data, so I get errors about undefined properties. What is the solution to this?

```
getKeyData: function () {
    for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
        k = ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key;
        ABC.PrintReport.reportData[k] = null;
        (function(index) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: ABC.Core.servicePath + '/task/' + ABC.PrintReport.processInstanceID + '/report/' + ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key + '?portalID=' + ABC.Core.portalID,
                success: function (response) {
                    ABC.PrintReport.reportData[index] = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText)[0];
                }
            });
        })(k);
    }
    window.open(location.pathname + 'resources/printreport.html');
},
```

Comment: Why not open it in the `success` function of your Ajax Request?

Comment: open the window in your success function

Comment: there are multiple ajax requests. Could be anything between 3 to 6. The requests are in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though there are a variable number of requests going on, you can keep track of them and open the window in the success method when the last request completes.

```
getKeyData: function () {
    var total = ABC.PrintReport.keyList.length;
    var loaded = 0;
    for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
        k = ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key;
        ABC.PrintReport.reportData[k] = null;
        (function(index) {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: ABC.Core.servicePath + '/task/' + ABC.PrintReport.processInstanceID + '/report/' + ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key + '?portalID=' + ABC.Core.portalID,
                success: function (response) {
                    ABC.PrintReport.reportData[index] = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText)[0];
                    loaded++;
                    if (loaded == total) {
                        window.open(location.pathname + 'resources/printreport.html');
                    }
                }
            });
        })(k);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using [deffered objects and promises](https://github.com/wilk/Ext.ux.Deferred)? Though I don't see a method `all()` that should help you resolve your problem, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024411/angular-q-how-to-chain-multiple-promises-within-and-after-a-for-loop).

I suggest using a [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), see the Combination section.

> The **all** function returns a promise for an array of values. When this promise is fulfilled, the array contains the fulfillment values of the original promises, in the same order as those promises.

Then you do:

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
    window.open(location.pathName + 'recources/printreport.html');
});
```

It's more clean than using a counter of already succeeded requests.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib, to create a parallel ajax calls and then call your callback with `window.open` when all AJAX request are done.