# Identifying angular spa app end of page render time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a SPA running on angular and we need to generate an event whenever a page has completed rendering after all of its ajax calls.

Any ideas that will prevent us from doing it on each page ?

Gil.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a service that will get signaled two times.

1. when the 1st request begins and
2. when the last response is
       collected (implemented via promises).

Then maybe you can broadcast a message that can be heard from the controllers, so they can start the rendering.

Well, not an expert here, so don't judge me too hard!

Comment: Hi victor,Thanks. But can u think of an automatic help to identify the last response?

Comment: Well you can use $q as shown here :

<http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056378/5867877>

Or you can enumerate them in a way, depending from there come from.

If the requests if from path A, then i expect 3 request/responses etc.